# How to merge 2 rows from 2 Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to merge a row from a dataset with another by doing a left join

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([, , [3656, 2532, 3652],["AFF", "KK", "DD"]]), columns=['Grp', 'A', 'B','C'])

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'Grp':[36, 25, 36,36], 'A':['GP', 'GP', 'GO','KO'],'B': [3656, 2532, 3652,3645],'C': ["AFF", "KK", "DD","ss"]}   
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# intialise data of lists. 
data2 = {'Grp':[36, 25, 36,36], 'A':['GP', 'GP', 'GO','JO'],'B': [3656, 25, 36,24],'C': ["AFF", "KK", "DD",'rr']}   
# Create DataFrame 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    df_left_2D = pd.merge(df,  row.iloc[3], on=['A','C'], how='left')
```

But I have this error:

```
 ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How about `df_left_2d = pd.merge(df, df2, on=["A", "C"], how="left)` ?

Comment: @Rafael  I would to select some rows

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the desired result after merging?

Comment: @Rafael yes  I am merginf it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be what you are trying to do is

```py
pd.merge(df,  df2, on=['A','C'], how='left')
```

your code is giving error because `row.iloc[3]` is a string and you are trying to merge df with a string which will not work

you can fix the error in your code like this but why are you merging one row at a time?

```py
for i in df2.index:
    df_left_2D = pd.merge(df,  df2.iloc[[i]], on=['A','C'], how='left')
```

Comment: I am merging one row at the time because for some rows I will do some specific algorithms